# Read Custom Node from OPCUA with C++ SDK - String as Node identifier

Tags: c++, sdk, opc-ua

I am using OPC UAs C++ SDK and trying to read custom nodes.

While executing the sample script provided, it works fine to read the Servers timestamp (following the Lesson 1: https://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdkcpp/1.5.5/html/L3GettingStartedClientLesson01.html)

Now I am trying to read a custom node, where the Node-Identifier is a String - Screenshot from UaExpert:

[image]

But I am having problem implementing it like this:

```
UaStatus SampleClient::read()
{
    UaStatus          result;
    ServiceSettings   serviceSettings;
    UaReadValueIds    nodeToRead;
    UaDataValues      values;
    UaDiagnosticInfos diagnosticInfos;
   // Configure one node to read
   // We read the value of the ServerStatus -> CurrentTime
   nodeToRead.create(1);
   //nodeToRead[0].AttributeId = OpcUa_Attributes_Value;
   //nodeToRead[0].NodeId.Identifier.Numeric = OpcUaId_Server_ServerStatus_CurrentTime;
   nodeToRead[0].AttributeId = 1;
   nodeToRead[0].NodeId.Identifier.String = "DISPLAY_VOLTAGE"; //"cant find operator which supports 
                                                               //type const char[16]"
   ...
```

I am also not sure if the AttributeIde is the Namespace-Number of the NodeID - but I didn't find anything else called "AttributeId".

Probably I need to implement my own attribute here - but I don't have an idea how:

```
typedef struct _OpcUa_String
{
    OpcUa_UInt          uReserved1;     /* Content is private to String Implementation */
#if OPCUA_STRING_SHORT
    OpcUa_UInt16        uReserved2;     /* Content is private to String Implementation */
#else /* OPCUA_STRING_SHORT */
    OpcUa_UInt32        uReserved2;     /* Content is private to String Implementation */
#endif /* OPCUA_STRING_SHORT */
    OpcUa_Void*         uReserved4;     /* Content is private to String Implementation */
} OpcUa_String, *OpcUa_pString;
#endif
```

Hope you guys can give me a hint how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found a way which works:

```
nodeToRead[0].AttributeId = OpcUa_Attributes_Value;
UaNodeId volt(UaString("DISPLAY_VOLTAGE"), 1); //("Identifierstring", Namespace)
volt.copyTo(&nodeToRead[0].NodeId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider posting your question on Unified Automation forum in the future since you are using their product.

I also think that this should work:

```
UaString volt("DISPLAY_VOLTAGE");
nodeToRead[0].NodeId.Identifier.String = volt;
nodeToRead[0].NodeId.Identifier.NamespaceIndex = 1; //(Added to reflect @jouni Aro comment)
```

The AttributeId, is a value representing the property of the Node you want to Read. In your case Value, so you should use OpcUa_Attributes_Value.

You could also use OpcUa_Attributes_DisplayName, OpcUa_Attributes_NodeClass, ... depending of which OPC UA properties of a Node you want to Read.
You can find the list of Attributes [here](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-AnsiC-Legacy/blob/8812bfb183a3a9d7a45ab715a59c752490df2217/Stack/stackcore/opcua_attributes.h)

Comment: Thanks, will post it there as well. Unfortunately your solution didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, it's missing the NamespaceIndex. Try 'nodeToRead[0].NodeId.Identifier.NamespaceIndex = 1' in addition. Although your own solution is good as well.